# What do I have to do to see the generated SQL with JBoss 6?

Tags: sql, logging, jboss

How can I make JBoss 6.0M2 show me the SQL that it generates and sends to the database?

Answer (score 2):

I have used p6spy for this in the past:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/

Hope that's helpful.